# AVG Time with miliseconds in MySql

Tags: mysql, time, average

I got a problem with AVG time (mm:ss.xxx) with MySql
My code is:

```
CREATE TABLE `tempFast` (
  `posicion` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lapTime` time(3) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



INSERT INTO `tempFast` (`posicion`, `lapTime`, `id`) VALUES
(1, '00:01:50.964', 1),
(1, '00:01:51.080', 2),
(1, '00:01:52.006', 3),
(1, '00:02:04.749', 4),
(1, '00:01:50.647', 5),
(1, '00:01:50.864', 6),
(1, '00:01:51.626', 7),
(1, '00:01:59.797', 8),
(2, '00:01:50.828', 20),
(2, '00:01:58.812', 21),
(2, '00:01:51.550', 22),
(2, '00:01:51.706', 23),
(2, '00:02:06.219', 24),
(2, '00:02:06.164', 25),
(2, '00:01:50.908', 26),
(2, '00:01:50.922', 27),
(2, '00:01:54.173', 28),
(2, '00:01:51.126', 29),
(2, '00:01:51.607', 30);
```

Then I would have the average time group by posicion. It suposs that poscion 1 should be **01:53,967** and for posicion 2 should be **01:54,910.**

I try to obtain with following query:

```
SELECT
posicion,
count(*) as cantidad,
SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(laptime))) AvgLapTime
FROM `tempFast`
group by posicion
```

It returns following bad result:

```
posicion    cantidad    AvgLapTime
1              8        00:01:53.3750
2              11       00:01:54.3636
```

How I can use Avg and have a good result? Thank you.

At https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/myTK8u1M72P5Z8NffDjPtV/0 you got the code to try

---

*** Uueerdo, finally your indications show me the way to manage this. With SEC_TO_TIME((AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(laptime) * 1000000 + MICROSECOND(laptime)))/1000000)

Comment: It would probably be better if you stored `lapTime` as an integer in millisecs, rather than `time`.

Comment: You could do `AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(laptime) * 1000000 + MICROSECOND(laptime))`, and then convert back to time.

Comment: Uueerdo thanks but I try AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(laptime) * 1000000 + MICROSECOND(laptime)) or SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(laptime) * 1000000 + MICROSECOND(laptime))) but results aren´t what expected (very high values).

Comment: Uueerdo, finally your indications show me the way to manage this. With SEC_TO_TIME((AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(laptime) * 1000000 + MICROSECOND(laptime)))/1000000)  returns the expected result. Thanks you

Comment: @pepqq I added a more thorough answer so you could mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since MySQL doesn't have a "to millisecond" function, one option is to use the MICROSECOND() function to get the fractional seconds, and TIME_TO_SEC() to get the time's total whole seconds, then `TIME_TO_SEC(laptime) * 1000000 + MICROSECOND(laptime)` to get entire microseconds. Average that, then divide by 1000000 to get back down to seconds, and then use `SEC_TO_TIME()` to get back to a time data type.

`SEC_TO_TIME((AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(laptime) * 1000000 + MICROSECOND(laptime)))/1000000)`

if times are large, you might also consider this variation where the average actually is calculated in milliseconds:

`SEC_TO_TIME((AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(laptime) * 1000 + MICROSECOND(laptime) / 1000))/1000)`